# How do call an Oracle Stored Procedure from a function

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a really complex Oracle Package that contains multiple procedures, functions, records and more. What I want to do is access the Stored Procedures as physical tables in the BI Admin tool but the tool does not support defining Oracle Stored Procedures as tables and suggests rewriting the SP as a function.

Instead of reinventing the wheel (Package). I was considering creating a new Oracle Function that called the stored procedure and accessing that function in the BI admin tool. My Question is ?

**"Can you call an Oracle Package from an Oracle Function ? - if yes examples ??"**

Don't let the not knowing BI dissuade you from answering this question - it did not stop me from asking it ;-)

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question.  Nothing can call a package because a package is not executable-- it is simply a collection of other objects some of which are executable.  A function can certainly call a procedure or a function that is defined in a package. If the procedure in the package is doing something that affects the purity level of the calling function (i.e. if the procedure modifies the state of the database) the function will not be callable from SQL (though it will remain callable from PL/SQL). And I don't see how this helps you access PL/SQL as a physical table.

Comment: In Oracle there are `FUNCTION` and `PROCEDURE` and `PACKAGE`. A `PACKAGE` can contain one or more `FUNCTIONS` and/or `PROCEDURES`. You can write a `FUNCTION` that calls a `FUNCTION` or `PROCEDURE` in a `PACKAGE` that is no problem. But the part of your question that is unclear is what you mean with accessing a stored procedure as a table. Can you give an example, screenshot of your BI tool (what tool do you use) etc?

Answer (score 0):

Are your Procedures returning a REF_CURSOR or something similar?  If so, then yes, you can easily write a pipelined table function that takes that cursor and pipes the results out.  See : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/tuning.htm#i52954

If not, please be more specific about what you are trying to do.